# Office 365 SharePoint Hosted App. Removed App from all the pages after deployment

Tags: office-365, office-365-developer

Office 365 SharePoint Hosted App. Removed App from all the pages after deployment. Is there any way we can preserve pages as it is. This is pain full activity to add app part again into to all the pages. Even its worst if site will go live.

Is there any workaround available to overcome this problem. Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have figure it out. Following is steps i followed.

1) Create App Catalog http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/publish-app-to-non-developer-site-collection

2) Each time when you change code you have to change the version number from the manifest file & Uploaded updated app into the App Catalog.

3) Click About link in App under Site Contents & It will show you the "there is a new version of this app. Get it now".

4) When you click on Get It button, it prompts you to trust it.

5) When you trust it, upgrade starts.

Once upgrade completed you will see the new code start reflecting.

Thanks